# Incompatible interface

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Please see the code below:

```
  Public Class clsCar
        Implements IVehicle
        Public Function getWheels() As Integer Implements IVehicle.getWheels
            Return 4
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Interface IVehicle
        Function getWheels() As Integer
    End Interface

    Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Dim list As List(Of IVehicle) = New List(Of IVehicle)
            Dim v1 As IVehicle = New clsCar
            Dim v2 As IVehicle = New clsBus
            list.Add(v1)
            list.Add(v2)
            Dim IVehicle As IVehicle = New clsCar
            Dim IVehicle2 As IVehicle = New clsBus
            For Each IVehicle In list
                MsgBox(IVehicle.getWheels())
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class
```

I want to add a new function to the clsBus class:

```
Public Function getWheels(ByVal strCarType As String) As Integer
        If strCarType = "Robin Ryliant" Then
            Return 3
        Else
            Return 4
        End If
    End Function
```

How do I call this from the FOR EACH statement? At the moment it will call getWheels with no arguments.

Comment: One possible solution is to make sure have the car type as a property or field on the object. THen call the parameterless version and let the object worry about whether it needs a type or not.

Comment: @Chris, thanks.  I think that would work for me.  Please post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your clsBus and clsCar are meant to refer to a specific car then the type should be a member of that class already, not something you pass in when you want to get information. To this end I'd suggest that you have "type" as something you can pass in the constructor and then the method on the bus would have no parameters and would just refer to its internal type to determine how many wheels it has.

I'm not too fluent with VB.NET so would probably make mistakes in example code but hopefully you get what I mean. If not I'll knock up some code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the method overload to the interface in order to be able to call it from a `IVehicle` variable.

```
Public Interface IVehicle
    Function getWheels() As Integer
    Function getWheels(ByVal strCarType As String) As Integer
End Interface
```

---

But probably it is better to have different, more specialized car types

```
Public Class clsCar
    Implements IVehicle

    Public Overridable Function getWheels() As Integer Implements IVehicle.getWheels
        Return 4
    End Function
End Class

Public Class clsRobinRyliantCar
    Inherits clsCar

    Public Overrides Function getWheels() As Integer
        Return 3
    End Function
End Class
```

This does not break the inheritance hierarchy and is purely polymorphic.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you call the function polmorphically? (in the for each loop.  All the other types do not accept a string.

Comment: If you want the method to only be on the bus then you aren't really being polymorphic. If you do what this answer suggests then you will have to have the method with a string on each of your implementing types. What you then do with it is up to you so you could just ignore the parameter and chain it to the parameterless version. The whole point of the interface is so you can treat them all the same though. If you don't want to do that then you shouldn't use an interface.

Comment: Thanks.  I will pass a string to each function.  Is it bad practice to do this? I guess not if it makes the types compatible via an interface.

Comment: I've just added an answer of my own which basically suggests that the clsBus should know what its type is already so you shouldn't be passing it as a parameter. Whether that works or not depends on your design though.

Comment: Olivier's solution of having a different type for three wheeled cars also works. It depends whether you want to define this by type or by data on the type.

Comment: Yeah, you can also pass the car's type as parameter to the constructor as Chris suggest; however, having constructs like `If strCarType = "xy" Then` or `Select Case` statements is often a hint that the code does not make an optimal use of object oriented principles.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would go for something more like this, with the number of wheels being an instance property (code in LINQPad format):

```
Sub Main

    Dim list As List(Of IVehicle) = New List(Of IVehicle)()
    list.Add(New clsCar("Ford Focus", 4))
    list.Add(New clsCar("Robin Ryliant", 3))
    list.Add(New clsBus())
    For Each v In list
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}:{1}", v.GetVehicleType(), v.GetWheels()))
    Next

End Sub

' Define other methods and classes here

Public Interface IVehicle
    Function GetVehicleType() As String
    Function GetWheels() As Integer
End Interface

Public MustInherit Class clsVehicle
    Implements IVehicle
    Protected Property VehicleType As String
    Protected Property Wheels As Integer
    Protected Sub New(vehicleType As String, wheels As Integer)
        Me.VehicleType = vehicleType
        Me.Wheels = wheels
    End Sub
    Public Function GetVehicleType() As String Implements IVehicle.GetVehicleType
        Return Me.VehicleType
    End Function
    Public Function GetWheels() As Integer Implements IVehicle.GetWheels
        Return Me.Wheels
    End Function
End Class

Public Class clsCar
    Inherits clsVehicle
    Public Sub New(vehicleType As String, wheels As Integer)
        MyBase.New(vehicleType, wheels)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class clsBus
    Inherits clsVehicle
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("Bus", 4)
    End Sub
End Class
```